# spotfire best way to get daily data from timespan

Tags: spotfire

I have some data that has multiple columns for simplicity lets call them "start" "End" and "duration". Duration comes pre calculated.

However I would like to show my data in daily or at least weekly figures. The data could be anything spanning several hours to several weeks or months. What would be the best way to get this data separated in this form?

I currently have extra columns calculating the part-duration for the new month but obviously with days or week it becomes quite cumbersome

Comment: How are you wanting to represent this? If the duration was in minutes, or seconds, or whatever... you could just change the X axis to the level of separation you want to show.

Comment: I want to show it in hours as a decimal. Data comes in from AMPLA in seconds but i'm already there.

I need to then show these in yearly,monthly,weekly and daily figures. But The way the data is at the moment I can only choose whether to count the day it occurred as either the start day or end day. For downtime data this doesnt make sense when its longer than 1 day/week etc.

At the moment I have created a couple of extra calculated columns to determine if it goes over the end of month and calculate the part-duration of the event that is in the new month.

Comment: You're already where? What's the expected output here?

Comment: I already have the duration split by month. I have manually added calculated columns which split the duration into Month1 and Month2. Obviously this does not account for an event that may span more than 2 months.

The expected output is to be able to filter by day/week/month/year and see the duration attributed to that time period